# Pagination From ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have ArrayList in my Constant file like below

```
public static ArrayList<ItemCategory> arrayListCategories = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am looking for display result with pagination so as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21452161/14423729)

I have tried below code

```
ArrayList<ItemCategory> arraylistsub = (ArrayList<ItemCategory>) Constant.arrayListCategories.subList(0,10);
        adapterCat = new AdapterCat(arraylistsub);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterCat);
```

But its getting error called

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList$SubList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

I am not getting idea, whats wrong with it and how I can resolve it. Let me know if someone here can help me for same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
ArrayList<ItemCategory> arraylistsub = new ArrayList<>(Constant.arrayListCategories.subList(0,10));
```